# how to get href link within a class in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting all the links of the page
I want only href links within the green box with the help class underlined green. Yellow underlined is href link

```
from selenium import webdriver;
webpage = "https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("xx\\xx\\xx\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(webpage)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li a")
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))

[Output] :- https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_September_2020.zip
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the header text and then find the next element.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[text()='Full Replacement Monthly NPI File']/following::a[1]")
print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

OR

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[./td[./b[text()='Full Replacement Monthly NPI File']]]/following-sibling::tr[1]//a")
print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: can't go with indexing because position of link changes all the time. One fix thing is that there will be a single link in the green box, so want to extract that only.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh : Check the updated answer and let me know how this goes?

Comment: it's working, that's really great. Thank You so much, could you please help me to download the latest version of csv file of link:- "https://www.nucc.org/index.php/code-sets-mainmenu-41/provider-taxonomy-mainmenu-40/csv-mainmenu-57", using same method

Comment: If this resolved your issue please mark this as accepted and vote for future reader.Thanks.

Comment: For your next query please post a new question for the same.

Comment: I have posted :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354008/how-to-get-the-href-link-of-latest-version-only-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='className']")

for link in links:

    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Or you can select a tag under the div>ul>li tags(or something else):

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='className']/ul/li/a")
for link in links:

    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

This works:

```
browser.get("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html")
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bulletlistleft']/ul/li/a")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: thanks, I already tried both and it gives an empty list

Comment: that gives me all the link of the page, I just want a yellow underlined href link, I can't give if condition with the name because it's dynamic.

Comment: Put all links in a list and use the first one. That is the yellow underlined href link.

Comment: can't go with indexing because position of link changes. One fix thing is that there will be a single link in the green box, so want to extract that only.

Answer (score 0):

I will get `pathname` attribute:

```
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("pathname"))
```