# how to get the href link of latest version only in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want the link of latest version of csv . If new version will come then I my program will pick latest href link.

> Output :- https://www.nucc.org/images/stories/CSV/nucc_taxonomy_201.csv

```
 home_page1 = "https://www.nucc.org/index.php/code-sets-mainmenu-41/provider-taxonomy-mainmenu-40/csv-mainmenu-57"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("xx\\xx\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(home_page1)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li a")
for link in elements:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the version in this case is 201? 
You can either use regex ```re.match(".*_(\d+)\..*", "https://www.nucc.org/images/stories/CSV/nucc_taxonomy_201.csv").groups()``` or if the format is consistent ```split()``` on ```.``` and ```_```

Comment: want to avoid split and regex, searching for a way which directly gives the latest link

Comment: Why do you oppose regex? Is there any reason it has to be done using selenium?

Comment: Yes, actually it was asked to using Selenium. I already tried this way. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iv looked at the website and its seems that you can do that by selenium
"find_element_by_xpath".
iv attached a photo.[image]

so the right XPATH IS

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/ul[1]/li/a
```

please check if its working again when the new version is coming.

and then you can look for it with this command :

```
login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/ul[1]/li/a")
```

let me know if it was helful.

Comment: That will break if the website structure only changes slightly

Comment: may I know how did you get black color console to match

Comment: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl)
its a google chrome add on.
And philip is right about the website structure but as you mentioned i gave you a solution using Selenum.

even though i would do that with requests only.

Answer (score 1):

Using some `regex` combined with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

#Find the tag containing the text 'current version'
current_version_tag = soup.find('p',text=re.compile('current version'))
#The download link will be the first link after it
download_link = "https://www.nucc.org" + current_version_tag.find_next("a").get('href')
```

**Output**

```
'https://www.nucc.org/images/stories/CSV/nucc_taxonomy_201.csv'
```